# Solving Differential Equations IN MATLAB For Different Values Of Input

Tags: matlab, nested-loops, runge-kutta

I have written a function plus a script to calculate and plot the response of a 1-degree-of-freedom system using 4th order runge-kutta method  in matlab. Here is the thing that I want to plot the response of the system for different values of inputs. I have zero initial conditions and the input is as follows:

```
F(t) = 5*sin(w*t)
```

Where w = [2 5 10]

I don't know how to use a loop in my function to form the state space for all values of w and
solve my equation and plot it for different values of w which makes a different input for each iteration. Notice that one way to do is write three different functions for all three cases and calculate the response.I do not want that. I just want a single function and my script which uses ode45 function to solve my differential equation but to plot the response for all values of w. How would You suggest me to do that. Here are my script and function:

```
function xDot = Myfnc(t,x)
global w
f = 5*sin(w*t);
%% Using State Space 

A = [0 1;-100 -1];
b = [0 f]';
xDot = A*x+b;
end




clc;
clear
close all;
%%
% y(..)+y(.)+100y = f(t)
% ZERO INITIAL conditions
% To A Harmonic Input
t = 0:0.1:15;
global w
w = 2;
Ics = [0 0];

[T,Y] = ode45(@Myfnc,t,Ics);

% plot(T,Y(:,1),'r','LineWidth',4)
% grid on
% hold on
% plot(T,Y(:,2),'k','LineWidth',3)
```

Comment: `DoPri45` is usually, like in `ode45`, implemented to use extrapolation, that is, the 5th order steps with the "wrong" error estimate, as that is for the 4th order step. So you get a 5th order method with adaptive step size. Do not forget to adapt the error tolerances to a level that is suitable to the result accuracy you want to obtain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What prevents you to loop over the values for `w`?

```matlab
for w in [2 5 10]
  [T Y] = ode45(@(t,y)Myfnc(t,y,w),t,Ics,opts)
  plot...
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for [arrayfun](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html). This allows you to apply an array of numbers to the same function.

For example if I have the following function:

```
function y = power(x)
   y = x*x;
end
```

Then I can use it as follows to apply it to different values:

```
X = [1 2 3];
arrayfun(@(x) power(x),X,'UniformOutput',false);
```

As you can see I'm using an anonymous function to wrap the power function.
Also I'm using 'UniformOutput' to be false so the function can return different types of elements inside a cell array. If you don't want cell arrays set it to true.

Comment: This only works if time and w vector have the same length.In my equation time vector has 100 numbers but w vector has 3 numbers.We can not use that